# Combining created columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query which returns columns from different tables, as well as a column that I've customized personally through a case statement.

```
SELECT table.column, 
CASE (...) as new_column
```

The thing is, I want to concatenate `table.column` and `new_column` in this query, although I can't independently call `new_column` since I created it in the query.

Due to database privileges, I can't actually create tables on the database.

Thoughts on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap that whole select into a `CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(table.column, CASE(...)) AS new_column
FROM table;
```

Another way of approaching it, not that I recommend it but it may be a little more readable, is to use your current query as a subquery and concatenate from the parent one:

```
SELECT CONCAT(column, new_column) AS new_column
FROM(
   SELECT table.column, CASE(...) AS new_column
   FROM table
) tmp;
```